# Run Powershell script on remote server accessible through local IP

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to create a `PSSession` from outside to a local machine basically using Azure tfs PowerShell task. The admin has given me a public IP, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. I get an error

> Network Path not available.

The network is divided into multiple local machines and I have to run PS Script on one local machine accessible through `192.168.15.14`.

Any help or guide related to solving this issue.

Comment: Please post your sanitized (no actual credentials or real-world IP addresses) code.
Are you trying to essentially do what Adam is describing in [this article](https://adamtheautomator.com/tfs-powershell-examples/)?

Comment: @Darrell, I don't have to manage TFS from Powershell, in fact, it's the way around, I have to run PowerShell script from TFS

Comment: are you saying the Powershell you need to run is stored in TFS or are you trying to manipulate Azure Pipelines via Powershell from within TFS?

Comment: I want to run powershell on local machine from TFS

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a remote session with the following code:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Set-Location D:\workspace}
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this & let you know it worked, but is the connection to the main DC already established in this case? and then I execute this command and then the commands which I need to do, right?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a little explanation

Comment: You could check the screenshot in my reply. The last line `[ComputerName]: PS workingdirectory` means the following script will run in the workingdirectory of the machine "ComputerName".

Comment: Is my reply helpful?